# Is it possible to catch ServiceException in OpenLayers?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, layers, vector, ows

I’m trying to catch exception in `OpenLayers` using vector layers in conjunction with the HTTP protocol, is it possible to intercept an `ServiceException` from GeoServer?

... it will be great to display some kind of error message when it happens.

Here's my snippet:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Foo", {
  projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
  strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
  reportError: true,
  protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
    url: "/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=ns:foo&outputFormat=json&viewparams=foo:var;",
    format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
  })
});
```

Ideas ??

Answer (score 1):

Try using the callback and see what it returns:

```js
var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Foo", {
  projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
  strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
  reportError: true,
  protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
    url: "/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=ns:foo&outputFormat=json&viewparams=foo:var;",
    format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
    callback: function(e) { 
       alert('Did at least something happen?'); 
       console.log(e);
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: This is a good lead. You will not be be able to catch a Service Exception on the client side, unless GeoServer informs the client of a ServiceException.  If it does you're in business, you can handle the exception appropriately.

Comment: good advice CaptDragon ... i try "callback" method previously but never executed ... HTTP protocol error ??

Comment: OptimizePrime, ServiceException was an example ... i want to catch error codes to ... like 404 or whatever ...

Comment: What does firebug say? You can also use Fiddler2. Do you see and HTTP WFS request being made ajax style?

Answer (score 0):

the issue comes from "OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed" this strategy overrides callback method, soo ... i create a fork from openlayers and implements event listeners for strategies ... take a look:

```js
var fixed = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed();

fixed.events.register("fail", this, function (response) {
  console.info("Fail.")
});

var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Foo", {
  projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
  strategies: [fixed],
  protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
    url: "/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=ns:foo&outputFormat=json&viewparams=foo:var;",
    format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
  })
});
```