# Is it possible to catch ServiceException in OpenLayers when ol.Protocol.WFS used?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, wfs, ows

I have openlayers-2. Can i intercept `ServiceException` when openlayers make request to GeoServer? I have found [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28024/is-it-possible-to-catch-serviceexception-in-openlayers) answer, but for HTTP protocol. However in my code is used WFS protocol. Here is how WFS protocol is created:

```
function getWFSProtocol() {
  return new ol.Protocol.WFS({
    geometryName: "Obj",
    url: clientSettings.map.layers['wfs'].url,
    featureType: "USA",
    featureNS: "http://www.mapinfo.com/wfs"
  });
}
```

I have tried to use `createCallback` like this:

```
function getWFSProtocol() {
  var protocol = new ol.Protocol.WFS({
    geometryName: "Obj",
    url: clientSettings.map.layers['wfs'].url,
    featureType: "USA",
    featureNS: "http://www.mapinfo.com/wfs"
  });
  protocol.createCallback(function(method, response, options) {
    console.log('wfs protocol callback called');
  });
  return protocol;
}
```

But callback not called response with `ServiceException`.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to create a response error callback?

```
var protocol = new ol.Protocol.WFS({
   geometryName: "Obj",
   url: clientSettings.map.layers['wfs'].url,
   featureType: "USA",
   featureNS: "http://www.mapinfo.com/wfs"
});
protocol.createCallback(function(method,response,options){
   response.error(function(e){
     alert(e);
   });
});
```

see

- http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Protocol-js.html#OpenLayers.Protocol.createCallback
- http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Protocol-js.html#OpenLayers.Protocol.Response.error

Comment: have tried - unfortunatly error callback not called :(